# background process pipe-input

Tags: pipe, background-process, stdin

if i want to display "aaa" on screen:

```
(1)$: echo aaa | cat                 ... works OK
(2)$: echo aaa | ( cat )             ... works OK
(3)$: echo aaa | ( cat & )           ... NOT working
(4)$: ( echo aaa & ) | cat           ... works OK 
(5)$: echo aaa | ( cat <&0 & )       ... works ok in BASH (but not in SH)
(6)$: echo aaa | ( cat <&3 & ) 3<&0  ... works ok in BASH and SH
```

conlusion from (3) and (4) -> detached process still have connected output that can be controlled, used, redirected..., but not input!

My question is: does someone understand **why and how line (5) works** ???

... "<&0" is short for "0<&0", why redirecting 0 to 0 is solution, and what really happens behind with input of detached process. Subshell's are not the problem, using braces {...} instead of (...) provide same results.

... and question2: is there better solution for "giving input to detached process" than line (6).

Comment: (6) worked for me. Not sure how I can run multiple commands of those in parallel, just like when we do `command1 & command2 & command3 &`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [as required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02), commands started in background with `&` have their standard input redirected from `/dev/null`.

And indeed

```
{ cmd <&3 3<&- & } 3<&0
```

is the most obvious way to work around it.

It's not clear why you'd want to run part of pipeline in background though.

Comment: reason was to get PID of one specific command inside pipe chain ( cmd1 | { cmd2 &; pid2=$!; } | cmd3 ... , so /dev/null==&0 is standard for BG proces, do you also know why "0<&0" works in bash ... and is it safe?

Comment: @OmerMerdan POSIX says _In all cases, explicit redirection of standard input shall override this activity_, which contradicts somehow what it said above, so I believe `bash` interprets it (and that sounds like a reasonable interpretation) as cancelling the `/dev/null` redirection. Now, not many shells do the same. Ash and pdksh don't.

Comment: Why it the `3<&-` part needed and is it safe to use it (will it not close the pipe before the full input ir read)?

Comment: What is the best way to combine it with `nohup`?

Comment: @Mvorisek, that fd 3 is only used temporarily to restore the original stdin. We close it as `cmd` doesn't need it. We close it after we have dupped it onto fd 0 (`<&3` short for `0<&3`).

Comment: @Mvorisek, `nohup` also redirects stdin to /dev/null, so you'd need: `{ nohup sh -c 'cmd <&3 3<&-' & } 3<&0`. Or `(trap '' HUP; cmd <&3 3<&- > nohup.out 2>&1 &) 3<&0`