# How to write a "compose" function of bash pipelines with named pipes

Tags: bash, io-redirection, fifo

[This page](https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/pipes.html#sec114) details psuedocode for creating a `compose` function that takes *n* commands and executes them in a pipeline:

> We program a command `compose` such that
>
> ```
> compose cmd1 cmd2 ... cmdn
> ```
>
> behaves like the shell command:
>
> ```
> cmd1 | cmd2 | ... | cmdn
> ```

I'm experimenting with [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) and I'm interested in actually writing `compose`, in Bash. Unfortunately I don't get any output when I do so, presumably due to race conditions reading and writing to the different pipes. I've made a number of iterations but keep getting confusing behavior. I've whittled it down to this smaller problem:

```
echo foo |   # stdin
{
  mkfifo p   # create pipe p
  cat > p &  # direct stdin to pipe p
  cat < p    # read pipe p to stdout
  rm p       # remove pipe p
}
```

I would expect this to output `foo`, but instead I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the example code in the question is subtle; in order to write to a named pipe you need to `&` background the command, otherwise it will block waiting to be read. However when you do so, "[*commands started in background with `&` have their standard input redirected [to] `/dev/null`.*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71205/19157)", meaning `/dev/null` is what's piped into `p`, rather than stdin.

In Bash the workaround is simple, redirect stdin to the backgrounded process with `0<&0`. Then the example will work correctly:

```
$ echo foo | { mkfifo p; cat 0<&0 > p & cat < p; rm p; }
foo
```

The full `compose` function ends up looking like so:

```
compose() {
  dir=$(mktemp -d)                 # Create a temp dir to hold the pipes
  cd $dir                          #   to avoid filename conflicts
  i=0                              #
  mkfifo "pipe$i"                  # Create pipe0, the output for command $1
  ($1 0<&0 > "pipe$i" &)           # Start $1, reading stdin and writing to pipe0
  shift                            # Shift off $1 since it's running
    for c in "$@"; do              # Loop over the remaining commands
    ii=$((i+1))                    # 
    mkfifo "pipe$ii"               # Create a pipe i+1, the next command's output
    ($c < "pipe$i" > "pipe$ii" &)  # Start the next command, reading from the
    i=$ii                          #   i'th pipe and writing to the i+1'th
  done                             #
  cat "pipe$i"                     # Output the last pipe, executing the commands
  cd - > /dev/null                 # Change back to the old directory
  rm -rf $dir                      # Remove all the pipes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
compose()
    case    $#  in  
    [01])  "$@" ;;          ## if 1 or fewer args just run what we've got
       *)  "$1" | {         ## otherwise pipe output from $1 into a
    shift; compose "$@"     ## self-call until all args are gone
};  esac
```

Comment: An explanation would be good.  I get nearly all of it but what's `[ -t 0 ]` for?

Comment: Well... @Wildcard - its not perfect, it was a cheap test to avoid hanging on a terminal if `compose`.

Comment: @Wildcard - oh, ok. it's perfect now. even returns correctly and everything.